# CREATE multi column constraint in mySQL as opposed to ALTER

Tags: mysql

## Question:

Is it possible to have enforce multiple column constraint when creating a table in mySQL, as opposed to later including it by altering the table?

## Background:

I have noticed almost all answers to the question "*how to create a multi column unique constraint in mySQL*" involve using `ALTER` on a table, here are 2 examples from here alone:

- [ON DUPLICATE KEY: multi-column unique constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889586/on-duplicate-key-multi-column-unique-constraint)
- [Use multiple columns as unique identifier for mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3798555/use-multiple-columns-as-unique-identifier-for-mysql)

The only examples I find which create multi column constraint when creating the table are for different flavors of sql:

- [How to place unique contraint on multiple column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968354/how-to-place-unique-contraint-on-multiple-column)
- [How to do multiple column unique-constraint in ormlite ( SQLite )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5264305/how-to-do-multiple-column-unique-constraint-in-ormlite-sqlite)
- [microsoft sql example](http://bytes.com/topic/sql-server/answers/169970-unique-constraint-multiple-columns)

Is there a way to create the constraint when creating the table as I find it is cleaner that way?

Comment: Is this a duplicate question, or has this question never been asked before by anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
   field1 int,
   field2 int,
   field3 int,
   UNIQUE KEY (field1, field2, field3)
);
```

Comment: The only thing I can think of that CAN'T be done in a `create table` as opposed to an `alter` later on is creating two+ tables with mutually referential foreign keys. You'd have to alter the first created table after the fact, since you couldn't create the foreign key initially because the foreign table doesn't exist (yet).